Sending File Via API from JavaScript Base64 encoded string to Java endpoint that accepts a Binary string (MultipartFile)
I am trying to send a file to a Java API endpoint from a JavaScript application. The Java endpoint accepts a binary string for the file in documentation. In the Java code it is accepting a MultipartFile. I've tried a few things to convert the JavaScript Base64 encoded file string, but still receiving "415: Unsupported Media Type".
Here is my recent code attempt:
  const handleFilesCallback = async (result) => {
    const fileBase64String = result.value.content; // get Base64 encoded file
    const byteCharacters = atob(fileBase64String); // convert to byte string
    let ia = new Uint8Array(byteCharacters.length); // build Uint8Array
    for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
      ia[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    const binaryString = new Blob(ia, { type: "" }); //create Blob        
    sendFile(binaryString);
  };

Here is the API call:
const sendFile = async (file) => {
  const response = await fetch(
    "javaApiUrl",
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        yourFile: file,
      }),
    }
  ).catch((error) => {
    console.log("error:", error);
  });
  const responseJSON = await response.json();
  return responseJSON;
};

How do I convert the Base64 encoded file string so the MultipartFile/binary string portion of the Java API is happy with what I send it?
UPDATE Java API Definition:
@Operation(summary = "Adds file somewhere")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200",
                    description = "File upload success",
                    content = @Content(
                            mediaType = "application/json",
                            schema = @Schema(implementation = Long.class)
                    ))         
    })
    @PostMapping(value = "/file/upload/url", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public Long addFile(@RequestParam("param 1") MultipartFile file) {
        
        return apiService.addfile(file);
    }

UPDATE 2
So I updated the request type and I am passing in a FormData object to the request body. The Java API STILL does not like the file format even though i send all formats. not one is accepted look here:
const handleFileCallback = async (result) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    const formData2 = new FormData();
    const formData3 = new FormData();
    const fileBase64String = result.value.content;
    const byteCharacters = atob(fileBase64String);
    let ia = new Uint8Array(byteCharacters.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
      ia[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    const fileBlob = new Blob(ia, { type: "text/plain" });
    const buffer = await fileBlob.arrayBuffer();
    const view = new Int8Array(buffer);
    const binaryString = [...view].map((n) => n.toString(2)).join(" ");
    formData.append("attachment", byteCharacters);
    formData2.append("attachment", binaryString);
    formData3.append("attachment", fileBase64String);

    sendFile(formData);
    sendFile(formData2);
    sendFile(formData3);
};

And the call looks like this:
const sendfile = async (file) => {
  console.log("upload entries:", Array.from(file));

  const response = await fetch(
    `javaApiUrl`,
    {
      method: "POST",
      body: file,
    }
  ).catch((error) => {
    console.log("error:", error);
  });

  const responseJSON = await response.json();
  return responseJSON;
};

Right now in the logs it doesn't recognize the "file" I pass it:
Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile.getSize()" because "file" is null
This call works in Postman, just not via my JS code.
Any insight is appreciated.

binary string this is wrong for Java. A String is not a binary and a binary is usually represented as a byte array. Please clarify exactly what are you trying to send.

Why don't you just send the result of atob()?

Base64 string  is correct but fails, atob byte string fails, Blob converted to binary string doesn't work. The swagger asks for binary string in request body, Java code would pass data in its own way aka MultipartFile. Perhaps it is how I am specifying "type" in Blob?

Share the Java API definition because this doesn't make sense.

Updated post with Java API definition so we have all the parts.

The request should be multiparty/form-data. The response is JSON. That's probably the problem. You've confused the response and the request in the API specification.

Ahhh good catch, I'm following this documentation  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest_API/Using_FormData_Objects  to adapt my JS. Getting 500 error now so I'm on the right track seems like.

I'm passing multipart/form-data  to the API now but it is getting an undefined file using const formData = new FormData();  to attach the file strings but still no luck.

I plan to post solution once i figure this out.  Also changed @RequestParam to @RequestBody in java code

You can compare the requests. The network monitor in the browser shows you the raw request, and Postman also shows you the raw request. Find the differences.

I think ultimately I just have to add a new Java endpoint that accepts a raw Base64 fileString which i will convert on java side rather than what I've been attempting. There is no easy conversion from Base64 fileString to File let alone a MultipartFile which I will also need new Java code to adapt to. I was avoiding adding a new endpoint or touching the Java code but i have no other option at this point. Thanks for the tips.

SOLUTION: Send the base64 file string WITH the file name to the Java side and convert it to a File there. MultiPartFile is no easily buildable from the JS side so my alternative was the solution.

Please don't post an answer in a comment. You can answer your own questions, but post an actual answer.

SOLUTION: Adapt Java API to accept base64 file string provided by Outlook Add-In and then convert the base64 file string on the Java side of the application like so...
JavaScript:
 const handleFilesCallback = async (result, fileName) => {
    sendFile(result.value.content, fileName);
  };

const sendFile = async (base64file, fileName) => {
  const response = await fetch(
    "java/Api/Url/files?filename=${fileName}",
    {
      method: "POST",
      body: base64file.toString(),
    }
  ).catch((error) => {
    console.log("error:", error);
  });
  const responseJSON = await response.json();
  return responseJSON;
};

JAVA API Endpoint:
@Operation(summary = "Adds file somewhere")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200",
                    description = "File upload success",
                    content = @Content(
                            mediaType = "application/json",
                            schema = @Schema(implementation = Long.class)
                    ))         
    })
    @PostMapping(value = "/file/upload/url", consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public Long addFile(@RequestBody String base64file, 
    @RequestParam("fileName") String fileName) {
        File newFile = new File("your/file/path");
        byte[] decodedFileBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64file);
        Files.write(newFile.toPath(), decodedFileBytes);
        return apiService.addfile(newFile, fileName);
    }

Tested this end to end file upload on Java side is successful after passing the file string from the JS.
